# SQLTool does not commit data after quit (HSQLDB)

Tags: sql, hsqldb, sqltools

i really dont understand the SQLTool... i just want to import a SQL File into the database and choosen this command to do this:

```
java -jar ~/bin/sqltool.jar --autoCommit --inlineRc URL=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/path/to/my/database.hsqldb,USER=SA,PASSWORD='' database.sql
```

in the database.sql is all the create stuff, like:

```
create table foo(id identity, name varchar(256));
```

then i have a second script, called data.sql, which should be written into the database the same, in this one is my whole testdata stuff:

```
insert into foo(name) values('bla');
```

when i now execute my bash script, the SQLTool creates a fresh database (before i deleted the file), but does not do anything with the SQL file!
The first script runs without errors, but the second says:

```
SEVERE  SQL Fehler an 'data.sql' Zeile 1:
"insert into foo (name) values('bla')"
user lacks privilege or object not found: FOO
org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool$SqlToolException
```

when i now connect to the database and say `\dt` there is no table!

i also put a `commit;` to the end of each file, and opend the SQLTool with `--autoCommit` but this doesnt work either... whats going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hsqldb requires SHUTDOWN command prior to last connection close or a JDBC connection property, shutdown=true. See [docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_closing_db).

Comment: +1  `;shutdown=true` may be appended to the URL to do this easily.

Comment: the link is dead.